# Lightning component error handleOnBlur event

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-events, onchange

I have an iteration on a component with an ui:inputNumber inside, which has an onchange event that calls a server side action. If after i change the value, i click on an input after the onchange is complete it throws me an error:

> Uncaught Action failed: ui:inputSmartNumber$controller$handleOnBlur
>   [Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined]

I have also tried this with the blur event but the error still persists.

Some code for a preview:

Component:

```
<aura:component controller="c_MyController" implements="force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="array" type="Object[]"/>
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.array}" var="obj">
         <ui:inputNumber value="{!obj.Number}" change="{!c.callAction}"/>
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
callAction : function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.myAction");

    action.setCallback(this,function(response){
        var state = response.getState();
        if(state === 'SUCCESS'){
            component.set("v.array", response.getReturnValue());
        }else if (state === "ERROR") {
            console.log(response.getError());
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

Server Side Controller:

```
 @AuraEnabled
public static List<MyObject__c> myAction(){
    return [Select Id From MyObject__c];
}
```

Edit: I believe that this is happening because of this line : `component.set("v.array", response.getReturnValue());` although it shouldn't. I believe the problem is that the focused element while the onchange event is running is rebuilt. But i have no idea how to workaround this issue.

Comment: can you post the "handleOnBlur" method of the controller that you are calling ? that might give more clue

Comment: Please post your server side code  & handleOnBlur code as well. You are facing error in handleOnBlur helper side.Please post that code

Comment: the code from the handleOnBlur method is from the aura_prod.js, that is the lightning standard js file. the code from my server side controller is not relevant, may be an empty method but ill put it there :)

Comment: are you calling same api to get array first time

Comment: I don't understand your logic - from what I see on an input change you are refreshing the whole list - that would trigger again the change event which will again take the object list from the server and refresh the list and again - looks like an infinite loop. what is your logic?

Comment: @ItaiShmida that is not the behavior. because when the list is rebuilt it will not trigger the onchange event again. My logic is exactly that but no loops happen. My edit is the reason this is happening, if i comment the component.set line this no longer happens. This is a javascript error that only happens if, when the list is rebuilt i am currently focusing an input inside the table.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with this logic? I still think that this what makes your technical problem

Comment: My goal is to be able to edit an input inside my table and call a server side action, that rebuilds my table. I am able to this without the error if i click on anything that is not another input to trigger the onchange event, but if i click on another input, this error occurs.

Comment: I can confirm that I'm seeing the same behavior right now.  I actually think it has to do with the fact that you're blurring away from a field, and focusing on another, then the controller method is essentially replacing the existing fields with new ones (i.e. you're replacing 'array').  So when the field you're now focused on is rerendered - it's causing another blur event, however now the original field no longer exists and it cannot be found when ui:inputSmartNumber rerenders itself.  I'm going to continue to search for a workaround, but this is new behavior i was not previously seeing.